# Use aggregation like LSP in C++

Tags: design, c++, implementations, liskov-substitution

I was reading about LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle) in a book called *Clean Architecture: A Craftsman's Guide to Software Structure and Design*. I have a question regarding how this would be implemented in C++.

On page 95, there is a figure explaining LSP using a simple example:

[image]

My interpretation of the figure in C++:

```cpp
// License.h
class License {
    public:
    virtual calcFee();
};


// PersonalLicense.h

#include "License.h"
class PersonalLicense : public License {
};


// BusinessLicense.h

#include "License.h"
class BusinessLicense : public License{
    private:
    someDataType users;
};
```

To my understanding, `Billing` will be using `PersonalLicense` and `BusinessLicense` (and other derivatives) *potentially*, so `Billing.h` will contain #include-s for all their header files:

```cpp
// Billing.h
#include "PersonalLicense.h"
#include "BusinessLicense.h"
...
```

My concern is that
a) if there are a lot of License derivatives, Billing.h will have to include all of them, and
b) it looks like Billing.h will have to be edited to include every new kind of License.
Is this the case? Or am I missing something?

## Update

After reading the [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/438660/334244) by Ryathal, I am now under the impression that I misunderstood the above figure. I was understanding the diagram as `Billing` has a `License`, which doesn't seem to be correct.

The aforementioned answer says that "This would be used in something like a shopping cart that does have references to all the different license types". This makes me think that the original diagram is incorrect, and that it should look like this instead (`ShoppingCart` has a `License`).

[image]

**Assumptios based on the above**

1. class `License` is defined in file named `License.h`.
2. class `PersonalLicense` is defined in file named `PersonalLicense.h` and includes `License.h`.
3. class `BusinessLicense` is defined in file named `BusinessLicense.h` and includes `License.h`.
4. class `ShoppingCart` is defined in file named `ShoppingCart.h` and its member function has expressions as such:

```cpp
...
list<License*> orders;
orders.add(new PersonalLicense());
orders.add(new BusinessLicense());
...
```

#### Questions

1. Which of the diagrams is correct, if any?
2. Is the diagram possible to implement using C++?
3. If we have multiple `License` types, let's say 5 ~ 10, do we have to include each header into `ShoppingCart.h`? Or is there any way of including as little headers as possible? I'm unsure how all this works in practice.

Comment: "let's say that we have thousands of `License` types" <- even if you have thousands of license types in your system, you almost certainly shouldn't have thousands of license _classes_. This is an indication you are missing a layer (or more than one) of abstraction.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Thousands of `License` types was just an way of explaining my question. If there is future plan for more `License` types which are defined as classes, such as `SchoolLicense`, `EducationLicense`, `DiscountedLicense`, and `FreeLicense`, will it be just including all headers into the `Billing.h`?

Comment: @Gooday2die - no, you shouldn't be including the headers of *any of them* in your Billing.h; that's the whole point. You'd only include Licence.h. The Billing class should not know anything about these, it should entirely work through the Licence interface. You'd have some *other* file (e.g. the one where the `main()` function is) where you'd create the Billing object by passing to it an instance of a concrete license subtype - you'd include the header file of that subtype there. Billing's constructor expects a License, but it will accept any subtype of License.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović -I understand that `Billing` shall not know or include any of following License types as well as that is the whole point of this diagram. However, I cannot think of any other ways of solving this problem and implementing this diagram with C++ while not including any of the `PersonalLicense.h` or `BusinessLicense.h`. Thus I was asking for "efficient way of solving this question" with this question.

Comment: *"However, I cannot think of any other ways of solving this problem and implementing this diagram with C++ while not including any of the PersonalLicense.h or BusinessLicense.h"* - sorry, but why? You code will compile and run fine without including PersonalLicense.h or BusinessLicense.h in Billing.h or Billing.cpp, as long as Billing don't uses a type like PersonalLicense directly. Try it!

Comment: @DocBrown I think I have confused everybody with my language. I understand that when `Billing` is not using member functions from `PersonalLicense` directly, it does not need to be included. I will modify my question a bit more specific.

Comment: If you're using member functions from the derived class, you're not using the Liskov principle and your title is wrong. If you're using the calcFee() function, defined as a virtual function in License.h, then even if the concrete type is PersonalLicense you do not need to use the header file to get the PersonalLicense version. Which is it?

Comment: @Gooday2die - if you have experience with a different programming language, maybe you could clarify by describing the thing in this other language that you're not sure how to implement in C++?

Comment: @Gooday2die "With my understanding, Billing will be using PersonalLicense and BusinessLicense potentially" - the idea is that Billing will *never* use any license subtype directly. You can *pass in*, say, PersonalLicense, but Billing *must not* see it as anything other then License. "If there is future plan for more License types which are defined as classes" - you wouldn't be including any new (or old) License (sub)types in Billing.h. The extending code (which may even be a separate project/library) can include Billing.h and License.h, and pass in the new class *as a License*.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at `Billing` from the wrong angle -- the key to LSP is **not** about the implementation of `class Billing` but about how `Billing` is used from the outside by other code.     The idea is that neither Billing.h nor Billing.cpp would come into any contact with the classes `PersonalLicense` or `BusinessLicense` because some external bit of code using `Billing` would supply the instances -  for example `myBilling = new Billing(new PersonalLicense());`

Comment: Not related,  but `;` is still required after the class definition in C++ ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First things first: the UML diagram

The original diagram is syntactically correct (except for the `<I>` on the box boundary, which should be `«interface»` centered above `Licence` in plain UML).

The diagram means, that `Billing` objects are associated to specific `Licence` objects and have access to their public feature, e.g. they may invoke their `calculateFee()` operation for calculating the bill.  The open-headed arrow means moreover that it is guaranteed that `Billing` objects can efficiently find the associated `License` objects.

The revised diagram is also correct.  ***Hint:** the use of the white aggregation diamond is not wrong, but it does not add any meaning to the diagram (despite a popular belief): the UML specifications still leave its semantics undefined.*

The main difference between the two diagrams is the multiplicity (it's unspecified in the first diagram, which in reality means that it's one to one if you take the UML specs by the book; it's one-to-many in the second).

### C++ implementation - step 1, polymorphism

The diagram can be perfectly implemented in C++, using polymorphism.  However, polymorphism requires some additional effort in C++.

The following example is not polymorphic and doomed to fail for your use case, because the way C++ handles objects:

```
class ShoppingCart {
public: 
    ...
private:
    std::vector<License> items;   // or std::list, if you prefer
};
```

The following alternative would be polymorphic:

```
class ShoppingCart {
public: 
    ...
private:
    std::vector<License*> items;   // the pointer allows to point to subtypes
};
```

But still, this is not sufficient. For polymorphism to work, the polymorphic object must also make the function that might be specialized `virtual`:

```
class License {
public: 
    virtual double calculateFee(); // ok double is not great for money, but it's another story
    virtual ~License();   // if one function is virtual, better foresee a virtual destructor as well
};
```

With this in place,  the shopping cart would not need to know anything about the many different kind of licenses that exist.  The compiler will make sure that in the following call the right member function is called:

```
total += items[n]->calculateFee();
```

### C++ implementation, step 2: Headers

You should have [self contained headers](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#sf11-header-files-should-be-self-contained) that include no more other headers than strictly needed to compile.  So in your case `ShoppingCart.h` should only include `License.h`.  If it doesn't compile, go to StackOverflow if necessary.

The only reason you would need the other headers, is if shopping cart would be responsible of the creation of the licenses:

```
orders.add(new PersonalLicense());
orders.add(new BusinessLicense());
```

But this should not be a responsibility of the shopping cart.  Because this would indeed require the cart to know much to much on all the specializations.  What you should have is some code like:

```
class ShoppingCart {
public: 
    void addItem(License* l); 
    double calculateTotal();  
private:
    std::vector<License*> items;   // the pointer allows to point to subtypes
};
```

So some other module would do the glue between the different kind of licenses and the shopping cart.  If you'd really have to let the cart create the items, then you'd need to use a factory to keep it general.

### And LSP in all this?

LSP means that your license specialization all continue to fulfill the contract guaranteed by `License`, so that whenever you use a `License`, you could exchange it with a more specialized license and the could would still work (as the contract is guaranteed).

If you don't have a polymorphic design in the first place, it makes no sense to talk about LSP.

Comment: I think the general outline of the answer is good and addresses most of the necessary points, given what the OP has communicated so far. Just wanted to comment on something, for clarity (since it was me who edited the question trying make it clear enough to be reopened): can't be 100% sure until we hear from the OP, but I'm under the impression that the OP's primary change to the diagram was not to turn the arrow into an aggregation or change the multiplicities (I think that was maybe coincidental, perhaps because of the UML tool used), ... 1/2

Comment: ... , but to replace Billing with ShoppingCart due to OP misunderstanding Ryathal's answer (where ShoppingCart was introduced as a hypothetical third component that references/includes headers for both License derivatives and Billing). I think the OP is confused about how the arrows in the diagrams relate to #include-s. While the second diagram is syntactically correct and could also make sense in this hypothetical system, due to this misunderstanding, the OP might see the two as contradictory, so your remarks about the second one may not hit home. 2/2

Comment: The answer covered most of my question that I was trying to ask. For Step 1, I am 100% clear with everything. For Step 2, *So some other module would do the glue between the different kind of licenses and the shopping cart.*, I still have question left to ask for efficient implementation of the "other module." Let's assume that we have a class named `ShoppingCartHelper` which generates different kind of `License`s and hands it over to `ShoppingCart` (so that `ShoppingCart` does not have to know all diffrent kinds of licences). ... 1/2

Comment: Then that makes `ShoppingCartHelper` necessarly "know" all different kinds of `License`s. Then if were to implement `ShoppingCartHelper`, is there any proper ways of making `ShoppingCartHelper` rather than letting `ShoppingCartHelper` know and include all headers of the different Licenses? or is it the only way of solving this kind of questions? While I was reading the answer, I realized that my question was implementing the `ShoppingCartHelper` in a proper and efficient way. (Again, sorry for making everybody being confused) 2/2

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Thank you for this helpful clarification.  To the OP's defense, the original wording of R.C.Martin may create confusion:  "*This class* [License] *has a method named calcFee(), which is called by the Billing application*".  Mixing up classes and applications is surprising for an author who advises not to mixup different abstraction levels.  Moreover, people less familiar with UML might be mislead to think that the arrow represents a call!

Comment: @Gooday2die The key to maintenable OO design is decoupling. This is why the shopping cart should not create the licenses itself.  In real world, you'd probably have an UI that lets user start an order.  And this would cause the construction of a new `ShoppingCart`.  The UI would have to display different kind of licenses,  navigate if needed interactively to a questionnaire (personal user vs. business user,  how many users) and adding it would need to know the possible licenses and how to create them.  The button "Add to cart" would then call `cart.add(license);` .

Comment: This design allows you to reuse code in another application that manages different kind of licenses.  Some element in your app must know exactly what license is to add,  and component shall do the glue.  It's not a helper class, but a different class with different responsibility.  `Billing`, `ShoppingCart` and `License` are domain classes (the user cares about them).  Very probably, the glue would be performed by some controller class (depending if you use [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller), MVP, MVVM or even ECB architectural approaches)

Comment: @Gooday2die about the efficient implementation,  it will necessarily depend on the architecture choice (see my previous comment).  But a typical approach is to use some tables,  that match some relevant characteristics to a [factory](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html). You can even use a single parametric factory that takes some arguments and choses the right license to build.  So yes, there are plenty of possibilities, but it quickly becomes a very broad subject ;-)

Comment: @Gooday2die A final remark is that if you have too many License specializations,  you might overly on inheritance and should think somewhat about preferring composition over inheritance, to keep the type hierarchy as flat as possible ;-)

Comment: Now everything is clear and makes sense right now. I will look into the factory method as well as avoiding too many licenses.

Answer (score 2):

For a demo of the Liskov Substitution Principle the header for Billing would only have License. The point of the LSP is that any object that extends another doesn't break that base functionality. Since Billing only knows about License for the LSP to be followed every extension must have an implementation of CalcFee that relies only on properties/functions that exist within license. When you violate the LSP its a good signal that your chosen abstraction is poor and you need to rethink the design. Inheritance really only works in somewhat small numbers (5 different licenses ok, 10+ might be a problem), in part because of the difficulty of following the LSP, which is why composition is more encouraged today as you can include similar functionality to objects, without directly relating them.

This is what Billing would look like:

```
Billing
{
  GetTotalFees(List<License> lic)
  {
    int total=0;
    foreach ( l in lic)
      total+=l.calcFee();
  }
}
```

This would be used in something like a shopping cart that does have references to all the different license types, so you could do something like:

```
Order.add(PersonalLicense);
Order.add(BusinessLicense);
Order.add(FishingLicense);
price=Billing.GetTotalFees(Order);
```

Comment: I guess I have confused a lot of people who tried to solve my problem with my language barrier. In the case like `Billing` that you have mentioned, `Billing.h` does not need to include any other headers but `License.h`. My original question that I was trying to ask was the part with *something like a shopping cart that does have references to all the different license types*. If we were to implement a "shopping cart", then will `ShoppingCart.h` has to include all different header files that declares Licenses? Is there any efficient and convenient way rather than adding each headers?

Comment: @Gooday2die - I guess what's confusing to people is that what you are asking about (shopping cart having references to all the different license types) is not specific to inheritance/LSP or C++. You'd have to add some kind of reference to the declarations of all the things you're intending to use (whatever those things might be) in any language. Organizationally, in C++, these #include-s don't have to be separate files, it can all be a single header file (or something in between), if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the user of the class tree - Billing in your example - needs to `#include` the header files for all your derived classes, then you're doing it wrong.

The first thing to try is *not* `#include`-ing them.  If your code still compiles, then you didn't need them.

If it does break, then that suggests you're using features of the derived classes that aren't in the base one.  This isn't actually a violation of the LSP, but is a "code smell".  Ask yourself why the other classes don't implement that feature, even if it's a "do nothing" option.  For example, if some licencees get discounts and others don't, then give all classes a "CalculateDiscount" function.  Ones that don't get discounts can return zero.  Such functions could be implemented in C++ as virtual functions on the base class, that derived classes may override if they wish.